# How to use a hotkey shortcut to run a launcher?

Tags: shortcut-keys, launcher

I have a launcher on my desktop. I would like to run it via a keyboard shortcut. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open keyboard shortcuts (`System>Preference>Keyboard Shortcuts`), and create the shortcut you want to add:

1. [image: img1]
2. [image]

Right click the launcher and click properties. Copy the information from the launcher where it says command (in the launcher properties) to where it says type here:

- [image]

Now save the keyboard shortcut (by clicking apply).

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I was looking for. Very didactic too !