# Hotkey combinations for window management?

Tags: shortcut-keys

What is the most useful hotkeys on ubuntu desktop ? (for show all windows at the same time, change between programs,...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**On Ubuntu 10.10 and early versions**

To see all windows at the same time : <kbd>superkey(win key)</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>

To see all Desktops at the same time : <kbd>superkey(win key)</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>

change between programs: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

The default ubuntu shortcuts see this:  [Ubuntu Hotkeys - Keyboard Shortcuts](http://allhotkeys.com/ubuntu_hotkeys.html)

To Define a shortcut  see this post answer [create a shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29036/how-to-use-a-hotkey-shortcut-to-run-a-launcher)

**On unity Ubuntu 11.04**

shows the Unity launcher <kbd>superkey</kbd>

Activates or opens the corresponding applications in the Unity launcher <kbd>superkey</kbd> + <kbd>{number}</kbd>

show all workstations(desktop) <kbd>superkey</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

To see all open programs on one workstation  <kbd>superkey</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Here is the a nice documentation of
[What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/unity-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts/28087#28087)

Answer (score 1):

[wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) is a neat application that can be used to do things like Windows 7 style maximize/left half/right half window movement and resizing shortcuts (or Mac's 2Up.)

Comment: You also can do this graphically with Compiz Settings Manager.

Answer (score -2):

1. Run a program: `ALT + F2`
   Ubuntu will show you suggestions, which makes this a very quick way to access your apps instead browsing all the menus
2. Switch workspace right or left : `CTRL + ALT + {ARROW}`