# Creating shortcuts to run applications conditionally

Tags: 10.04, shortcut-keys

I was wondering if it is possible to create a keyboard shortcut to run application if it is not yet running in Ubuntu?

This is a valid example for something like a browser which is normally heavily used, and you wouldn't really want to run another instance of it if there is one running already (rather just activate the window).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a hotkey shortcut to run a launcher ?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29036/how-to-use-a-hotkey-shortcut-to-run-a-launcher)

Comment: @Takkat: I think the "one instance" requirement make this question different from that.

Comment: I guess you could write a script that launches a browser conditionally. Then how to activate the browser window if it already exists?

Comment: This is the default for firefox, without the `-no-remote` option, an already started instance is used.

Comment: Cool, what about `Chrome`?

Comment: @Leonid Google Chrome, Chromium, and any icons you add to Unity's launcher already do this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Save the following [script](http://pastebin.com/ukVB7H74) to your home folder as `launch_chrome.py`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python

   import subprocess
   import wnck
   import gtk
   import time


   screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
   while gtk.events_pending():
       gtk.main_iteration()

   window_list = screen.get_windows_stacked()

   last_active = None
   for window in window_list:
       if window.get_application().get_name() == "Google Chrome":
           last_active = window

   if last_active:

       timestamp = int(time.time())
       last_active.activate(timestamp)

   else:

       subprocess.Popen("google-chrome")
   ```
2. Make the script executable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/launch_chrome.py
   ```
3. Use the command `/home/<YOURUSERNAME>/launch_chrome.py` when [adding a shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29036/how-to-use-a-hotkey-shortcut-to-run-a-launcher).

When this shortcut is activated, it will either:

1. Launch a new Chrome window if there aren't any already running or,
2. bring the most recently used Chrome window into focus.

Comment: nice one. works for me.

Comment: I adapted the script to activate sublime text editor, but the issue  I have is that the keyboard is not on focus after sublime is activated. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

In *Ubuntu* there is a package called `run-one` that is close to what you ask.

I report the description:

```
 This utility will run just one instance at a time of some command and
 unique set of arguments (useful for cronjobs, eg).
```

Regarding the keyboard shortcut, see here [How to use a hotkey shortcut to run a launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29036/how-to-use-a-hotkey-shortcut-to-run-a-launcher).

Regarding the "if there is one running already, just activate the window", I don't know. Not all applications have a window, they may have zero or more than one window. And even in the case of a single window, I don't know of a simple way to map a process to its window.